# How to bind multiple different services for android?

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

I want to start 2 services at the start of an activity but only the first one starts and the second fails at `bindService()`. There is no error just when I want to do something with the service it gives me a nullpointer. I also tried to wait to do something but the service never starts.

The 2 services are pretty similar and I just want to know what is wrong with the implementation. I tried to debug and `bindservice()` function at startSoundmanagerService return 0, what is maybe the root of the problem but I don't know why.

```
public class SimulationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BluetoothService BService;
    boolean mBound = false;
    SoundManager SService;
    boolean sBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            setStatusText("Bluetooth on");
        }
        else {
            setStatusText("Bluetooth off");
        }
        if(!mBound) {
            startServer();
        }
        conStatImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.connection_off);
        if(!sBound){
            startSoundManagerService();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(mBound) {
            unbindService(bConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        if(sBound){
            unbindService(sConnection);
            sBound = false;
        }


    }

    private ServiceConnection bConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                        IBinder service) {
                BluetoothService.LocalBinder binder = 
                (BluetoothService.LocalBinder) service;

                BService = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
        

    private ServiceConnection sConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                    IBinder service) {
        
            SoundManager.LocalBinder binder = (SoundManager.LocalBinder) service;
            SService = binder.getService();
            sBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        sBound = false;
    }


    public void startServer(){

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.d("tag","Device doesn't support Bluetooth") ;
        }

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            startBluetoothservice();
        }

    }

    private void startBluetoothservice(){

        Intent intent = new Intent (this,BluetoothService.class);
        bindService(intent, bConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.i(TAG,"Trying to start bluetoothservice");
    }
    private void startSoundManagerService(){

        Intent intent = new Intent (this,SoundManager.class);
        bindService(intent, sConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.i(TAG,"Trying to start soundservice");

    }
```

So how can I implement 2 different services in 1 activity?

Edit Solution: I forgot to register the service in the manifestfile. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: I forgot to register the 2nd Service in the manifest. Thats all ;)